# Non-trivial $R$ has identity iff $R^2 = R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The exercise ask me to give a counterexample of $R^2 = R\implies R$ has identity, where $R$ is a ring. I find $0$ satisfies. However, is there other non-trivial examples ? That's to say whether if $R$ is non-trivial($R\neq 0$) ring $R^2 = R \iff R$ has identity is ture or not ?

I think it true, since if we have some 'order', that's true. However I cannot express it clearly.

Thanks !

Comment: The zero ring does have identity! It's just that $1=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\bigoplus_\Bbb N \Bbb F_2$ with componentwise addition and multiplication. Here every element is idempotent, thus in particular $R^2=R$, but there is no identity.

In fact, take any infinite family $R_i$ of non-zero rings with identity, then $R:=\bigoplus R_i$ is also a counterexample. The reason here is that for any $r \in R$, there is an element $u \in R$ such that $ur=r$. Maybe one could call that "having local identities" or something, I'm no expert on rng theory.

Here's an example of a different flavour:
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Consider $C_c^\infty(M)$, the ring of smooth real-valued functions on $M$ with compact support. Since there are plenty of "bump functions" on $M$, one can find for every $f \in C_c^\infty(M)$ with support $K$ a function $u \in C_c^\infty(M)$ which is identically $1$ on $K$. But then $uf=f$ and we have "local identities" as above. This ring has an identity iff $M$ is compact.

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but isn't $(1, 1, 1, ..., )$ the multiplicative identity? Maybe what you wanted was to restrict this to "finitely many non-zero terms"? (that might be what you're implying with $\oplus_\mathbb{N}$?)

Comment: @CalvinLin indeed, that's what I am implying. The direct sum of modules, (abelian) groups or, well, rngs is the subset of the direct product consisting of those elements with only finitely many non-zero terms. I didn't write $\prod_\Bbb N \Bbb F_2$

Comment: @CalvinLin "$\bigoplus$" denotes the [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum), not the direct product.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't complete, but I thought it was a nice example.

Consider $R = \sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1]} 2^q\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$, as a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.

To show $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to show it's closed under differences (easy) and it's closed under multiplication, which can be shown on the level of monomials as
$$(2^ra)(2^sb) = 2^{r+s}(ab) = 2^{r+s-1}(2ab)$$
where the second form is used if $r+s > 1$.

Then if $0 < q_1 < q_2 < \ldots < q_n \leq 1$ is a sequence of rational numbers, then $0 < q_1/2 < q_2-q_1/2 < \ldots < q_n-q_1/2 \leq 1$ and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{q_k}a_k = 2^{q_1/2}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{q_k-q_1/2}a_k$$
shows that $RR=R$.

The only fact I haven't showed, though I'm fairly convinced of its truth, is that $1 \not\in R$.

Comment: I like this construction, but I also don't see how to prove $1\not\in R$ immediately (surely it's true though ...).

Comment: Couldn't you use an extension of the $2$-adic valuation to $\Bbb R$ to show that it is not unital?

Comment: @LukasHeger I don't think I ever learned the more number-theory-adjacent algebra topics, so... perhaps?  I don't know enough to actually investigate whether that would work.  The frustrating part is that it _feels_ like it should be immediately apparent that $R$ isn't unital (especially since, as a nonzero subring of $\mathbb{R}$, there's only one candidate), and perhaps if I look at it with fresh eyes in the next couple days I'll see some simple method, but I'm coming up blank right now.

Comment: Let $v$ be an extension of the $2$-adic valuation to $\Bbb R$. Then $v(2^q)=q$ by an easy argument. Also $v(m)\in \Bbb N$ for all $m \in \Bbb Z \setminus 0$ and hence $v(2^qm)=q+v(m)$ Now if $q,q' \in (0,1]$ are distinct, this implies that $v(qm)\neq v(q'm')$ for $m,m' \in \Bbb Z \setminus 0$. Thus by a standard property of valuations $v(\sum_{i=1}^kq_im_i)=\min(v(q_im_i))>0$ for $q_i \in (0,1]$ distinct and $m_i \in \Bbb Z\neq 0$. But $v(1)=0$, thus the ring doesn't contain $1$.